# CouchDB Security in a Lightweight Stack?

Tags: couchdb

I'm working on a hobbyist project in order to become more familiar with CouchDB. This is my first time working with CouchDB. For this project, my goal is to investigate whether or not it's possible to build a web application with nothing but HTML, CSS, JavaScript, CouchDB, and nginx (i.e., I'm not hosting any of my code in Couch, just data).

It could be that this is highly impractical, but I'd first like to explore all the options in this stack.

At the moment, my biggest questions are about security. Let's say that I have a few databases in CouchDB, each corresponding to a hosted site. For this example, we'll focus on a single database-- i.e., a single site. Some of the content from this site should be available to everyone, even anonymous users; and other stuff should only be available to users with a certain role. What are my options, and how secure are each of them?

I've come up with a few ideas so far, and this is the one I was planning to work on over the weekend:

1. Add users and roles to `/{site_db}/_security`.

   - [According to the Couch documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview), doing so will require any request for data in `{site_db}` to be from an authenticated user.
2. Add a user called `anon`, which will only have one role, which is `anon`.
3. When the user first visits the site, my JS model will check the status of the current session (`GET /_session`).

   - If no session exists, the JS model will authenticate using the `anon` account.
4. Define views in my design document.

   - Any views that should only be available to non-anonymous users should check the roles on the `userCtx` object.
   - Validation of any newly-created documents should check `userCtx` to see if the user's role is on the whitelist.

This seems like it should work, although I can't help thinking it's overly complex, and that there must be a better way. Also, I'm not sure how to prevent the `anon` user from updating his own user document to add more roles.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like CouchDB security model, you can implement yours easily in your reverse proxy instead.

Here is an [example with Apache](https://github.com/benel/Setting-up-LDAP/wiki#set-ldap-authentification-for-argos-steatite-or-cassandre) but it seems to be [very similar in nginx](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy#Authentication_with_reverse_proxy).